# How to position the dynamically created widgets in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

I am creating widgets dynamically based on the number of field names in a layer using PyQGIS. The widgets gets created successfully, but its not positioned properly. Is there a way to position the lineedit box to the middle using Python?Below is my code for creating widgets dynamically.

```
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]
for i,field in enumerate(fieldnames):
    self.labels = QLabel()
    self.linedit = QLineEdit()
    self.labels.setText(field)
    self.linedit.setFixedWidth(100)
    self.dlg.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labels)
    self.dlg.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.linedit)
```

[image]

I want the textboxes to be placed something like this

[image]

Comment: What do you mean they are located in the middle? You could explain what you want to get with a graphic.

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain the same order of a form you must use `QFormLayout`.

```
selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]
flay = QFormLayout()
for field in fieldnames:
    le = QLineEdit()
    le.setFixedWidth(100)
    flay.addRow(field, le)
self.dlg.verticalLayout.addLayout(flay)
```